# pyodbc cannot find unixodbc library when using Anaconda Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, pyodbc, unixodbc

I want to use Anaconda Python 3.6 to do data analysis. And I use unixodbc to connect to database. When I use Anaconda Python I got

```
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.4.0' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

but if I run `python2 db.py`, which is using system Python. Everything goes well.

I'm not sure whether my environment or file permission set correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at os.environ and make sure that /opt/rest/ofpath is on you rpath to be found?

Comment: Thanks. But can you tell me how to check that? Is that in `os.environ['PATH']`

Comment: if still relevent, what does `odbcinst -j` give you ?

Comment: im having the same issue, the output is to /etc/... i dont know where conda install -c anaconda unixodbc is placing the files